# Web application to allow users to pick and choose objects used as building blocks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, caching, user-interface

I'm currently developing an application using ASP.NET MVC, and now I need to create an interface (web page) that will allow the users to pick and choose from a set of different objecs, the ones they'd like to use as the building blocks for constructing a more complex object.

My question is supposed to be generic, but to provide the actual example, let's say the application that will allow users to design pieces of furniture, like wardrobes, kitchen cabinets, etc.  So, I've created C# classes representing the basic building blocks of furniture design, like basic shapes (pieces of wood that added together form a box, etc), doors, doorknobs, drawers, etc. Each of these classes have some common properties (width, height, length) and some specific properties, but all descend from a basic class called FurnitureItem, so there are ways for them to be 'connected' together, and interchanged. For instance, there are different types of doors that can be used in a wardrobe... like SimpleDoor, SlidingDoor, and so on. The user designing the furniture would have to choose wich type of Door object to apply to the current furniture. Also, there are other items, like dividing panels, shelves, drawers, etc. The resulting model of course would be a complete customized modularly designed wardrobe or kitchen cabinet, for example.

The problem is that while I can easily instantiate all the objects that I need and connect them together using C#, forming a complete furniture item, I need to provide a way for users to do it using a web interface. That means, they would probably have a toolbox or toolbar of some sort, and select (maybe drag and drop) items to a design panel, in the web interface... so, while in the browser I cannot have my C# class implementation... and if I post the selected item to the server (either a form post or using ajax), i need to reconstruct the whole collection of objects that were already previously chosen by the user, so I can fit the newly added item... and calculate it's dimensions, etc. and then finaly return the complete modified set of objects...

I'm trying to think of different ways of caching, or persisting theses objects while the user is still designing (adding and deleting items), since there may be many roundtrips to the server, because the proper calculation of dimentions (width, height, etc of contained objects) is done at the server by methods of my C# classes. It would be nice maybe to store objects for the currrent furniture being designed in a session object or cache object per user... even then I need to be able to provide some type of ID to the object being added and the one being added to, in a parent owner kind of way, so I can identify properly the object instance back in the server where the new instance will be connected to.

I know it's somehow confusing... but I hope this gives one idea of the problem I'm facing... In other words, I need to keep a set of interconnected objects in the server because they are responsible for calculations and applying some constraints, while allowing the users to manipulate each of these objects and how they are connected, adding and deleting them, through a web interface. So at the end, the whole thing can be persisted in a database. Idealy I want even to give user a visual representation or feedback, so they can see what they are designing as they go along...

Finally, the question is more so as to what approach should I take to this problem. Are C# classes enough in the server (encapsulating calculation and maybe generating each one it's own graphical representation back to the client)? Will I need to create similar classes in javascript to allow a more slick user experience? Will it be easier if I manage to keep the objects alive in a session or cache object between requests? Or should I just instantiate all objects that form the whole furniture again on each user interaction (for calculation)? In that case, I would have to post all the objects and all the already customized properties every time?

Any thoughts or ideas on how to best approach this problem are greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the way you've described it, here is what I'm envisioning:

1. It sounds like you do want a slick looking UI so yes, you'll want to divide your logic into two sets; a client-side set for building and a server-side set for validation.  I would get heavy on the javascript so that the user can happily build their widget disconnected, and then validate everything once it's posted to the server.
2. Saving to a session opens a whole can of webfarm worms.  If these widgets can be recreated in less than a minute (once they've decided what they like), I would avoid saving partials all together.  If it's absolutely necessary though, I would save them to the database.
3. If the number of objects to construct a widget is reasonable, it could all come down at once.  But if there are hundreds of types of 'doors' you're going to want to consider asynchronous calls to load them, with possible paging/sorting.
4. I'm confused about your last part about instantiating/posting all objects that form the whole furniture.  This shouldn't be necessary.  I imagine the user would do his construction on his client, and then pass up a single widget object to the server for validation.

That's what I'm thinking anyway... by the way, hello StackOverflow, this is my first post.

Comment: +1 - nice post mddubs (tho mr dubs sounds kinda better :) - oh and welcome to SO

Comment: saving to a session only has webfarm issues if you don't have a state server, or aren't persisting your session information in a database.  either of those things should pretty much solve that issue.

Comment: @jim - thanks!  mr dubs does have a nice ring to it but at this point I'm committed :)

Comment: +1 for some succinct, useful, guidelines; a very nice first post. :) welcome!

Comment: Thanks mddubs for taking the time to provide these guidelines... they helped me to think of some new ideas about how to solve this.. I was almost stuck... Now I'll be looking into creating a richer javascript layer instead of trying to solve it mostly at the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) for this kind of project. It allows you to create client-side models, collections, views and controllers that would be well suited to your problem domain. It includes built in Ajax code for loading/saving those models/collections to/from the server.

As far as storing objects before the complete object is sent to the server, you could utilize localStorage, and store your object data as a JSON string.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer as well... from mddubs answer, I'll be really looking into some better ways to create a richer javascript layer to help me in this task. I glanced over Backbone.js and Knockout, and will be studying them more deeply. @nathan... thanks for your indication of Knockout as well...